# Making sound after given interval of time in android

Tags: android, time, intervals

I am making an app in which I have 2 `Button`s. Now I want that when I click on **button1** it will make sound after given interval of time and keeps on going making sound in an infinite loop until and unless I don't press **button2**. Suppose button1 & Button2 is Start & stop respectively.

I am displaying date & time in `Toast` now just for example. Like when I click on **button1** it displays a toast.

Now I want that is should keep displaying toast at given interval of time until and unless I don't press **button2**.

For now I can only display a toast on **button1**'s click as I am confuse on how to set the loop.

Can any one please help me with my query. It would be a great help for me. By the way I am still learning.

Here is my code of button1 i.e `StartBtn`:

```
StartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            playSoundWithDelay();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
    }

    private void playSoundAfterDelay() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Play Sound;
                // Repeat after 1 sec
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }

        }, 5000);
    }
```

To stop Sound/Toast when app is closed or in background, add this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

Comment: It worked for me.
I am again using toast just for example.
The problem is that when i press start, it show me toast but when i press stop still it displays the toast. Even after exiting the app keeps on showing me the toast. so i have to force stop it.

Comment: Just call mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) in your onPause().

Comment: i don't have onPause() in my code. what to do now. Can you please guide. Thanks

Comment: got it and worked as well thanks :)
But what about stopping the toast when i press stop button.